# How to disable code folding in Qt Creator?

Tags: ide, qt-creator, code-folding

I have a project I'm working on in Qt Creator that requires breakpoints to debug. I would like to be able to add a breakpoint by clicking next to the line number, because it is intuitive to me. However, when I click in Qt Creator, the code is folded and and no breakpoint is added.

I can toggle a breakpoint by pressing F9, so this is not the main issue. I can even add a breakpoint by clicking on the left of the line number. However, I tend to click on the right of the line number, which results in folding my code. Can I disable code folding somehow?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can hide the folding markers by unchecking **Edit > Preferences > Text Editor > Display > Display folding markers.** See the relevant part of the documentation: [Highlighting and Folding Blocks](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-highlighting.html#highlighting-and-folding-blocks).

For older versions of Qt Creator, see **Tools > Options > Text Editor > Display > Display folding markers**